# What features will I lose if I upgrade a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra from Android 13 to Android 14, if any?

Tags: updates, android-13, android-14, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I have a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13. What features will I lose if I upgrade a it from Android 13 to Android 14, if any?